# Nodejs async multiple tasks updating the same array

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Is it okay to pass the global variable jobQueue this way?  Thanks for your help.

```
var jobQueue = [];
async.parallel([
    function(){
       watchForFileChangeAddToJobQueue(jobQueue);
    },
    function(){
       listenForHttpRequestAndAddToJobQueue(jobQueue);
    },
    function(){
       runLongTaskToProcessJobsInJobQueue(jobQueue);
    }
]);
```

Comment: I think it's OK if all your *JavaScript* code just appending element to this array, since they will be executed in the single thread that will not introduce concurrency. But not pretty sure, correct me if anything wrong.

Comment: passing the variable that ways its ok, but processing with `.parallel` will make it fail, try `.cargo` or `.queue` calling the callback when its supposed to end, set a high concurrency so many tasks can be executed and but not stress the machine that this is running..